# Truncate text on left in UITextField

Tags: text, ios, uitextfield, truncate

I need to truncate text on the left in a UITextField. So, for example, it would show as "... blind mice, three blind mice, see how they run" instead of "three blind mice, three blind mice, see...". It's more important for the user to end of the string, rather than the beginning, so this is quite important.

This is easy enough in a UILabel, by setting UILabel's lineBreakMode property to UILineBreakModeHeadTruncation. However, UITextField seems to have no such option.

Does anyone know an easy way around this?

Comment: is your UITextField going to be editable?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible if you make keyboard visible calling following code

[self.yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];

Then larger text is clipped from left.

you can also hide keyboard [if you use any custom keyboard] using following code

```
// Hide keyboard for Dial Pad, but show blinking cursor
UIView *dummyKeyboardView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
yourTextField.inputView = dummyKeyboardView;
[dummyKeyboardView release];
```